# Nativescript plugins problems occur after recent updates

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, nativescript, google-geolocation

I am working on a Nativescript project that for some time now has incorporated the ‘nativescript-google-maps-sdk’ and ‘nativescript-geolocation’ plugins without problem.

But recently, I’ve started getting errors when building, and trial-and-error elimination has narrowed it down to the inclusion of either of these plugins.  Specifically, I get the error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
```

In searching around for this, it seems as though this is an Android library version conflict somewhere, and I am led to discussions about ‘migrating to androidX’, but none of the mitigations suggested in these threads have yielded any positive results.

Is anyone else having this problem, or more importantly: does anyone have a solution recommendation?

(BTW: It continues to build fine on iOS)

I've verified I'm fully updated to {N} 5.4.3 and have updated my platforms as well.

I've removed and added both plugins to insure latest versions.

here are the dependencies from  my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "geodesy": "^1.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "nativescript": "^5.4.0",
    "nativescript-camera": "^4.1.1",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^4.4.2",
    "nativescript-google-maps-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^6.0.6",
    "nativescript-intl": "^3.0.0",
    "nativescript-multi-select": "^1.0.6",
    "nativescript-sqlite": "^2.3.3",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "^3.10.0",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^5.2.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.3.4",
    "nativescript-websockets": "^1.5.3",
    "sourcemap-codec": "^1.4.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.4.3",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.3.1"
  },
```

Comment: http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=942 this outlines the AndroidX changes that are happening across Android development and of course NativeScript.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem perfectly (I used option 1).  I looked all over for something like this.  Thanks for the link!